# Launch app using DeepLink in MAUI iOS for testing in Appium

Tags: ios, appium, maui, appium-ios

How to navigate to particular page using Deeplink in iOS platform in Appium ?

For android we can use below code,

```
this.appiumDriver.ExecuteScript(
    “mobile: deepLink”,
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { “url”, $“sampleApp://LoginPage” },
        { “package”, “com.test.sampleapp” }
    });
```

Is there any way similar to this in iOS ?
else we need to follow conventional way of navigating to safari → Paste URL → Click open → Page opened in app ???

I tried to open the app via Safari and was somewhat successful too but that seems long process.